# Why is open('file','w') saying file doesn't exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, ubuntu

I have a function:

```py
def loadFile(file):
    path = script_dir + file #script_dir has the form '/home/username/blah/blah/' and file has the form 'asdf/foo.txt'
    temp = open(path,'w')
    temp.close()
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read().replace('\n', '')
```

When I run `print(loadFile('asdf/asdf.txt'))` in python3, I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/username/blah/blah/asdf/asdf.txt'
```

Why is this happening?  I am very confused.  everywhere I look it says that `'w'` will create the file, why isn't it.

Note1: I run Zorin OS Education Lite (sorry I can't provide you with more universal terminology).
Note2: I have an NTFS partition mounted at `/home/username/blah/`

Comment: Does `asdf` directory exist in current working directory?

Comment: What does the `pwd` return ?

Comment: @Cyttorak no, I would expect it to create it, but it worked, thanks.

Comment: @JayPatel I'm not sure what you mean.  What's a `pwd`?

Comment: use `os.makedirs(os.dirname(path), exists_ok=True)` before you open the file for writing, and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

`open(path,'w')` will certainly create the file at `path` if it doesn't exist, but only if all the directories in the path already exist. That is, it creates a file but it won't create directories.

(Also, it can't create the file unless you have write permission for the directory in which the file will be created. But that will give you a different error message.)

Comment: Thanks, @Cyttorak had the solution.

Answer (score 0):

open(path,'w') will create the file, but it can't create the directory by itself. Please check the appropriate 'asad/' directory is present in the script folder and you have the appropriate write permission in the folder.
In case, you can create a folder in the directory from where you run the script and ensure you have write permission with the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also tell Python exactly where the file is on your computer
regardless of where the program that’s being executed is stored. This
is called an absolute file path. You use an absolute path if a relative path
doesn’t work. For instance, if you’ve put text_files in some folder other than
python_work—say, a folder called other_files—then just passing open() the
path 'text_files/filename.txt' won’t work because Python will only look
for that location inside python_work. You’ll need to write out a full path to
clarify where you want Python to look